# Rails: Getting the most recent datetime in a child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parent-child

I have the parent model of `user` and `user` `has_many :events`. From the `user` view, how can I find the most *recent* datetime (`event.time`) of `event`?

I'm thinking that a find_by will work, but I'm not sure on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.

```
user.events.find(:first, :order => "time DESC")
```

You can read more here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001777

Comment: For some reason, when find returns the results, it is in a weird format. Here's an example: `#<Event:0xb6a26708>` What's going on?

Comment: the result returned is an Event instance. Try _result.time_

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say `result.time`. How do I use that?

Comment: user.events.find(:first, :order => "time DESC").time

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. And I did have that, but I was having trouble when user didn't have any events. I added an exception and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

`user.events.find(:all, :order => 'time desc', :limit => 100)`
where limit is number of recent events you need or:
`user.events.find(:first, :order => 'time desc')`
if you need one most recent event.

Answer (score 0):

```
user.events.find(:first, :order => 'time desc').time
```

like this you can get the event time

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this, the find first helper:

```
user.events.find(:first, :order => 'time desc').time
```

is now deprecated and removed as of Rails 3.2. You should use

```
user.events.order("time desc").first.try(:time)
```

instead.